# Flink table left outer join showing an error

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-table-api

I am doing a **left outer join** on two tables in flink, and the code is given below, showing an exception, **inner join** with the same two tables worked fine and was able to convert to Datastream

```
Table table = customerTable.leftOuterJoin(contactTable,$("cust_custcode")
.isEqual($("contact_custcode")))
.select($("customermessage"), $("contactmessage"));
```

The exception is : org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Table sink '*anonymous_datastream_sink$3*' doesn't support consuming update and delete changes which is produced by node Join(joinType=[LeftOuterJoin], where=[(f0 = f00)], select=[f0, f1, f00, f10], leftInputSpec=[NoUniqueKey], rightInputSpec=[NoUniqueKey])

Answer (score 0):

When executed in streaming mode, some Flink SQL queries produce an output stream than the planner knows will only need to INSERT rows into the sink, while other queries produce an output stream that sometimes needs to UPDATE previously emitted results.

Some sinks cannot accept UPDATE streams -- including the one you are using. You'll need to either (1) change your query (e.g., by doing a windowed join), (2) use a different sink (e.g., JDBC can accept updates), or (3) write to the sink in a different format (e.g., a CDC format like debezium).